# Proguard shrinking causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, proguard

There is a video activity in my android app.
In debug build when proguard is disabled all works like a charm.
But in release build when proguard is enabled and the video activity starts I get a NPE.

Part of my gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        versionNameSuffix '-dev'
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.com.tv24.news/ua.com.tv24.news.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at ua.com.tv24.news.ui.fragments.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.i(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.u.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.u.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.u.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.u.j(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.p.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at ua.com.tv24.news.ui.activities.a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at ua.com.tv24.news.ui.activities.b.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at ua.com.tv24.news.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

And my Activity:

```
 package ua.com.tv24.news.ui.activities;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.exoplayerextensions.Video;
import com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.layeredvideo.PlaybackControlLayer;
import com.google.googlemediaframework.adplayer.ImaPlayer;

import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;
import ua.com.tv24.news.R;
import ua.com.tv24.news.events.ui.VideoPreparedEvent;

public class DashVideoActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements PlaybackControlLayer.FullscreenCallback {
    private ImaPlayer imaPlayer;
    private FrameLayout videoPlayerContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_video);
        videoPlayerContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_frame);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String videoUrl = bundle.getString(VideoActivity.VIDEO_URL_EXTRA);
        String appName = getString(R.string.app_name);

        //TODO get url and name from extras
        VideoItem video = new VideoItem(appName, new Video(videoUrl, Video.VideoType.DASH, ""),
                null);

        createImaPlayer(video);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (imaPlayer != null) {
            imaPlayer.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (imaPlayer != null) {
            imaPlayer.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (imaPlayer != null) {
            imaPlayer.release();
        }
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void createImaPlayer(VideoItem videoListItem) {
        if (imaPlayer != null) {
            imaPlayer.release();
        }

        // If there was previously a video player in the container, remove it.
        videoPlayerContainer.removeAllViews();

        String adTagUrl = videoListItem.adUrl;
        String videoTitle = videoListItem.title;

        imaPlayer = new ImaPlayer(this,
                videoPlayerContainer,
                videoListItem.video,
                videoTitle,
                adTagUrl);
        imaPlayer.setFullscreenCallback(this);

        Resources res = getResources();

        Drawable logo = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.launcher);
        imaPlayer.setLogoImage(logo);

        imaPlayer.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGoToFullscreen() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReturnFromFullscreen() {
    }

    public static class VideoItem implements Parcelable {

        /**
         * The title of the video.
         */
        public final String title;

        /**
         * The actual content video (contains its URL, media type - either DASH or mp4,
         * and an optional media type).
         */
        public final Video video;

        /**
         * The URL of the VAST document which represents the ad.
         */
        public final String adUrl;

        /**
         * @param title The title of the video.
         * @param video The actual content video (contains its URL, media type - either DASH or mp4,
         *              and an optional media type).
         * @param adUrl The URL of the VAST document which represents the ad.
         */
        public VideoItem(String title, Video video, String adUrl) {
            this.title = title;
            this.video = video;
            this.adUrl = adUrl;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        }
    }

    public void onEventMainThread(VideoPreparedEvent event) {
        View progress = findViewById(R.id.videoLoaderBar);
        if (progress != null) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Also my proguard rules:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# Picasso 
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

#okhttp
-keepnames class com.levelup.http.okhttp.** { *; }
-keepnames interface com.levelup.http.okhttp.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keepnames interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

#retrofit
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-dontwarn rx.*
-keep class com.example.testobfuscation.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @ua.* <methods>;
}

-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.**

-keep class ua.com.tv24.news.models.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses

#xml parser
-keep interface org.simpleframework.xml.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.** { *; }

#eventBus
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent(**);
}
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEventMainThread(**);
}

#support v7
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }

#unusage classes
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
-dontwarn retrofit.RxSupport$1
-dontwarn com.google.ads.a.a
-dontwarn com.google.ads.a.c
-dontwarn com.google.ads.a.d
-dontwarn com.google.ads.a.f
-dontwarn com.google.android.exoplayer.hls.HlsMediaPlaylistParser
-dontwarn okio.DeflaterSink
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider
-dontwarn okio.Okio
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text
-dontwarn retrofit.RestMethodInfo$RxSupport
-dontwarn retrofit.RxSupport
-dontwarn retrofit.RxSupport$2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taker care that you excluded classes and methods from ProGuard processing:

```
# Hide warnings about references to newer platforms in the library
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
# don't process support library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

The error occurs usually, if [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is involved because Proguard can't resolve the dependencies in this case.

I just see you missed the interfaces in your ProGuard file (as per exception):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ...
```

Comment: not a perfect approach, to be honest, it's not a approach, only get around the real problem

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur on proguard's optimize process, but my problem was a little diference, the crash log is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cmcm.gamemoney_sdk_style2/com.cmcm.gamemoney.Main3Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.app.l.s(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
       at android.support.v7.app.l.r(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
       at android.support.v7.app.l.b(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
       at android.support.v7.app.i.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.cmcm.gamemoney_sdk.Main3Activity.onCreate(Main3Activity.java:41)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.l.a()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.widget.s.setBackgroundDrawable(AppCompatImageButton.java:124)
       at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:21620)
       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5553)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:176)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:96)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:92)
       at android.support.v7.widget.s.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.y(Toolbar.java:1362)
       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.c(Toolbar.java:918)
       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:322)
       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:229)
       ... 29 more
```

the key point at **AppCompatImageButton#setBackgroundDrawable()** so I decompile the apk's code and found the obfuscated method code like this:

```java
public final void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable var1) {
    super.setBackgroundDrawable(var1);
    this.a.a();
}
```

compare to before proguad's code is:

```java
public void setImageDrawable(@Nullable Drawable drawable) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    if (this.mImageHelper != null) {
        this.mImageHelper.applySupportImageTint();
    }
}
```

which means the proguard process remove the `null check` incorrectly, and why? after check the AppCompatImageButton's source code, I found **mImageHelper** was define as final also meant to initial in constructor:

```java
private final AppCompatImageHelper mImageHelper;

public AppCompatImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(TintContextWrapper.wrap(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.mBackgroundTintHelper = new AppCompatBackgroundHelper(this);
    this.mBackgroundTintHelper.loadFromAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.mImageHelper = new AppCompatImageHelper(this);
    this.mImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

the problem is before it's initialling, `super` is the first line of constructor, and it end up call **setImageDrawable()** ahead of the initialling, that cause the crash.

I dislike to use `-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }` to solve this problem, as I said, this is get around the problem, also put down all advantages of proguard to make the apk size grow unnecessarily.

first solution is declare in proguard configuration to mark dont optimize:

```
-dontoptimize
```

but that will disable all optimizations, take no benefit of optimize process.

so the best solution I can find is:

```
-optimizations !field/propagation/value
```

it mark don't optimize the fixed value's invoke.

by the way, during tracing where are the real problem, I switch to macOS from Windows 10, found the problem only occured in Windows 10, I check the diferences only found the jvm version not equals, macOS is "1.8.0_73" but Windows 10 is "1.8.0_221", otherwise such as proguard version both are 6.0.3, and both the proguard-base-6.0.3.jar's md5 are identical.

---

Update 1 (after six hours later):

there are something else, after fixed this problem and move on, I encounter another problem:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cmcm.gamemoney_sdk_style2/com.cmcm.cmgame.activity.H5GameActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.cmcm.cmgame.e.a$a
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.cmcm.cmgame.e.a$a
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2875)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2700)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086)
       at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7718)
       at com.cmcm.cmgame.activity.H5GameActivity.M(H5GameActivity.java:209)
       at com.cmcm.cmgame.activity.H5GameActivity.onCreate(H5GameActivity.java:628)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
       ... 9 more
```

**requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR**

I remember android already kept the Parcelable's CREATOR on its default proguard file clear, why didn't apply?

I have the build.gradle print the default proguard file location:

```
println "default android proguard file : ${getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')}"

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

the log is :

```
default android proguard file : C:\dev\cmgameSdkDemo_localconfig\build\intermediates\proguard-files\proguard-android.txt-3.2.1
```

and I didn't found the `proguard-android.txt-3.2.1` file on that directory accordingly, which means the default proguard file never apply so the two problems rised, I go to MacOS and take this file, on its head I see:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
#
# Starting with version 2.2 of the Android plugin for Gradle, this file is distributed together with
# the plugin and unpacked at build-time. The files in $ANDROID_HOME are no longer maintained and
# will be ignored by new version of the Android plugin for Gradle.
```

also that file contained `-dontoptimize` as I mention before, and yes I used `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`.

so, the real problem is gradle(gradle-5.0-milestone-1-all used) on Windows 10 failed to(or never) pull **proguard-android.txt-3.2.1** to project's root build folder make it no apply and the subsequent problems, I think it is some kind of bug of Android plugin for Gradle, only we can do is discard **getDefaultProguardFile** and use local default proguard file of android.

```
proguardFiles "${rootDir}/proguard-android.txt-3.2.1", 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

I copy that `proguard-android.txt-3.2.1` file from my MacBook, in case you don't know where to find it, you can go to your android sdk install directory, that file was sit as tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

---

Update 2 (after 15 hours later):

this problem are project related, I switch to another project on my Windows 10, the Gradle version still **gradle-5.0-milestone-1-all**, and the Android plugin for Gradle still **com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1**, that project can pull `proguard-android.txt-3.2.1` without crash.

so the **best solution** is rename the project, then enter project directory, delete the `.idea` and `.gradle` in root, delete all *.iml in sub-modules, all the way is make a new project than before, end up open it in AndroidStudio the problem will gone.

another solution is go to `C:\Users\lingyx` directory, delete the **.AndroidStudioPreview4.0**\system\caches\project_resources\$project_name, for linux it will be ~/.AndroidStudio[version info depends on your env]/system/caches/project_resources/$project_name